# Convert the uploaded images to Ckeditor into base64?

Tags: ckeditor

I have installed ng2-ckeditor. I wanted to know how i can get the images added to the editor to be converted to base64 and appended to the image tag.

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/base64image was added with the intent to help with the conversion but is there another way to just convert the images to base64

```
<img alt="" 
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QZJgABAgEYAgA/7gA.......9g+3iXJ//Z" />
```

i wanted to appened the base64 to the tag as displayed above

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use relative path instead of base64 string. When relative path cannot be used you can convert the image to base64 string as describet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42483385/2795402). When you work with ng2-ckeditor you can convert your image in angular code.

Comment: can u elaborate how i can convert it do i need to add a plugin or is there a way to access the image handler?

Comment: You can convert the image in TypeScript as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42483385/2795402)