# Converting an Image url to base64 in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

I am struggling trying to convert a given image url to base64... in my case i have a String with the image's path

```
var imgUrl = `./assets/logoEmpresas/${empresa.logoUrl}`
```

how can i convert the given image url in a base64 directly?... i tried this post.

> [Converting an image to base64 in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482951/converting-an-image-to-base64-in-angular-2)

but this post is getting the image from a form... how can i adapt it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Comment: Also if you are using @angular/cli, you do not need to do a relative path like `../../../../../assets`. You can simply do `assets/logoEmpresas/${empresa.logoUrl}`.

Comment: thanks for your tips, taking a look to that post

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this to get base64 image

```
async function getBase64ImageFromUrl(imageUrl) {
  var res = await fetch(imageUrl);
  var blob = await res.blob();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        resolve(reader.result);
    }, false);

    reader.onerror = () => {
      return reject(this);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  })
}
```

Then call it like this

```
getBase64ImageFromUrl('your url')
    .then(result => testImage.src = result)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Works perfectly in my Angular project :)

Answer (score 2):

> works like charm in pdfMake and angular

You can use this function to create generate a base64 image

```
    toDataURL = async (url) => {
    console.log("Downloading image...");
    var res = await fetch(url);
    var blob = await res.blob();

    const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        resolve(reader.result);
      }, false);

      reader.onerror = () => {
        return reject(this);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    })

    return result
  };
```

> and then call it like this

```
imageSrcString = await this.toDataURL(imageSrc)
```

Answer (score 2):

##### If we're doing this in Angular, we may as well make use of [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) and a [Service](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#creating-an-injectable-service).

Let's go ahead and add the [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule) into our related Module, we'll need this in order to use HttpClient.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpClientModule],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then let's create a generic Image Service, and then ask Angular to [inject](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#dependency-injection-tokens) the HttpClient into our Service.

```js
@Injectable()
export class ImageService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

Once that's done we can actually create our function in our service

```
imageUrlToBase64(urL: string) {
  return this.http.get(urL, {
      observe: 'body',
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    })
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      map((arrayBuffer) =>
        btoa(
          Array.from(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer))
          .map((b) => String.fromCharCode(b))
          .join('')
        )
      ),
    )
}
```

When we use **http.[get](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get)** and provide `arraybuffer` as our `response type`, Angular interprets the `body` of our request as an `ArrayBuffer`. What that means is that we'll now have our image as an array of bytes. All we need to do is then convert our `ArrayBuffer` to a `base64` string. If you'd like to view alternative options, this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string) has good answers.

```js
// taken from above
map(
  btoa(
    Array.from(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer))
    .map((b) => String.fromCharCode(b))
    .join('')
  )
)
```

Now that the function is done, we can shift to usage:

```
@Component()
export class AppComponent {
  base64Image: string;
  constructor(private imageService: ImageService) {
      this.imageService.imageUrlToBase64('https://picsum.photos/200/300').subscribe(
          base64 => {
              this.base64Image = base64
      })
  }
}
```

We'll now have access to the image as a base64

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer... but it gives me an error, when i try with your URL it works but if try with any other URL it fails ( HttpErrorResponse in console ), what is happening? the url that im trying is... https://img-01.stickers.cloud/packs/0ba639f2-873a-447c-8f1d-80f6378523d0/webp/436e532a-8330-4bf3-a8cb-a5679eb0e9ed.webp
Or...
https://clientes.infowork.es/74042-thickbox_leomega/tpvtactil15bluebeej194gb64gbaluminio.jpg
Any help is apreciated!

Comment: Are you prefixing your URL with `https://`?

Comment: yep, i'm typing the url exactly how i copied here, very weird error... i finally decided to download and convert it in my node server... i think i can deal better with errors , but would be interesting to solve this error :S

Comment: You're probably running into a CORS error - that would be a whole other issue to solve!