# Error [Object object] when trying to upload file to Firebase storage

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2, angularfire

I've been trying to upload an image to Firebase storage on Angular. Here is a piece of code

```
const randomId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
const ref = this.storage.ref(randomId);
const task = ref.put(file);
```

Error happens on the last line

I replaced the last line with another way to upload (according to angular documentation)

```
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
```

But the same error happens

here is the error:

```
ERROR Error: [object Object]
at viewWrappedDebugError (core.js:22194)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:36417)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:36043)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:22533)
at core.js:33721
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:1789)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:30885)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
```

Comment: Can you try uploading base64 of the image?

Comment: What is the base64 of the image?

Comment: Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42483385/6513921) and [here](https://medium.com/@barvysta/firebase-storage-base64url-string-you-are-going-to-have-troubles-40be1ef56521).